# Exporting one branch from command line

Tags: lyx

Is it possible to activate a LyX branch from the command line while exporting?

The [documentation](https://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/ImportExport#cl) says that the following command should work, but it does not in my tests.

```
lyx -x "command-sequence branch-activate b1" -E pdf2 outfile.pdf infile.lyx
```

You can test this with the following minimal LyX file and the above command. In the resulting PDF you should find "AAA CCC" but, instead, only "CCC" appears.

```
#LyX 2.3 created this file. For more info see http://www.lyx.org/
\lyxformat 544
\begin_document
\begin_header
\save_transient_properties true
\origin unavailable
\textclass article
\use_default_options true
\maintain_unincluded_children false
\language english
\language_package default
\inputencoding auto
\fontencoding global
\font_roman "default" "default"
\font_sans "default" "default"
\font_typewriter "default" "default"
\font_math "auto" "auto"
\font_default_family default
\use_non_tex_fonts false
\font_sc false
\font_osf false
\font_sf_scale 100 100
\font_tt_scale 100 100
\use_microtype false
\use_dash_ligatures true
\graphics default
\default_output_format default
\output_sync 0
\bibtex_command default
\index_command default
\paperfontsize default
\use_hyperref false
\papersize default
\use_geometry false
\use_package amsmath 1
\use_package amssymb 1
\use_package cancel 1
\use_package esint 1
\use_package mathdots 1
\use_package mathtools 1
\use_package mhchem 1
\use_package stackrel 1
\use_package stmaryrd 1
\use_package undertilde 1
\cite_engine basic
\cite_engine_type default
\biblio_style plain
\use_bibtopic false
\use_indices false
\paperorientation portrait
\suppress_date false
\justification true
\use_refstyle 1
\use_minted 0
\branch b1
\selected 0
\filename_suffix 0
\color #faf0e6
\end_branch
\branch b2
\selected 0
\filename_suffix 0
\color #faf0e6
\end_branch
\index Index
\shortcut idx
\color #008000
\end_index
\secnumdepth 3
\tocdepth 3
\paragraph_separation indent
\paragraph_indentation default
\is_math_indent 0
\math_numbering_side default
\quotes_style english
\dynamic_quotes 0
\papercolumns 1
\papersides 1
\paperpagestyle default
\tracking_changes false
\output_changes false
\html_math_output 0
\html_css_as_file 0
\html_be_strict false
\end_header

\begin_body

\begin_layout Standard
\begin_inset Branch b1
inverted 0
status open

\begin_layout Standard
AAA
\end_layout

\end_inset


\end_layout

\begin_layout Standard
\begin_inset Branch b2
inverted 0
status open

\begin_layout Standard
BBB
\end_layout

\end_inset


\end_layout

\begin_layout Standard
CCC
\end_layout

\end_body
\end_document
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following:

```
lyx -x "command-sequence branch-activate b1; buffer-export pdf2; undo; lyx-quit" infile.lyx
```

You can use `buffer-export-as` instead, if you would like the file to be named something other than infile.pdf. The "undo" is to avoid a dialog that asks if you would like to save changes. It is not elegant, and there should be a more natural way to do what you want, but I don't know if there currently is one.

By the way, nice minimal example. It made it easy to attempt to answer your question.

Comment: Thanks Scott. The branch selection works, but the `lyx-quit` command is problematic because real-life files require a while to be processed and it seems that there isn't a way to wait until the conversion is done.

Comment: For the record, `buffer-export pdf2 outfile.pdf` is the correct way to specify the output filename. `buffer-export-as` shows an interactive dialog.

Comment: Another one for the record: there is a race condition between `undo` and `buffer-export`. Sometimes `undo` will undo the branch selection before `buffer-export` is done, exporting the document as if the branch had never been activated.

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem by manipulating the lyx file directly using sed. This gets around the race conditions and is especially nice for scripting up large custom exports.

```
sed -e '/\\branch b1/,+1s/\\selected.*/\\selected 1/' < infile.lyx > tmp.lyx
lyx -E pdf2 outfile.pdf tmp.lyx
rm tmp.lyx
```